# Undefined method `layout' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have method in my `class Site::BaseController < ApplicationController`

```
before_filter :check_layout

   def check_layout
    if @user.site_theme == 'hometastic'
      layout 'hometastic'
    else
      layout 'agent'
    end
  end
```

When i do only

```
layout 'agent'
```

it works perfectly

but when i added `before_filter` i have got `undefined method layout for`

Rails  3.2.16

Any suggestions?
 [error screen](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/684887/3175ae6815a1e60da7a1490815f1de7c)

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/684887/3175ae6815a1e60da7a1490815f1de7c @Pavan

Comment: What happens when you change `layout` to `self.class.layout`?

Comment: self.class.layout 'hometastic' works @Pavan

Comment: @xxx have you tried japed's answer

Comment: @Pavan can you explain why  `layout` doesnt works? only `self.class.layout`

Comment: Is your method under the `private`?

Comment: @Pavan,no its public

Comment: I'm guessing the word `layout` cannot be used in the instance methods directly. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a symbol which Rails will use to evaluate it when a request is processed. [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#choosing-layouts-at-runtime)

```
layout :themed_layout

def themed_layout
  if @user.site_theme == 'hometastic'
    'hometastic'
  else
    'agent'
  end
end
```

Comment: or simply `@user.site_theme == 'hometastic' ? 'hometastic' :  'agent' `

Comment: Yes, if you prefer ternary operators.

Comment: you only need to return `theme string` ..i.e `'hometastic' or 'agent'` calling layout inside layout might result in an error,

Answer (score 1):

just add the following lines of code in application controller:

**include ActionView::Layouts**

Comment: but after this i have receive another error :
NoMethodError: undefined method `helper' for ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:Class

Comment: i have also same issue but after modification in application controller just add ::base
means our application controller is inherited from Base 
"class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base"

Comment: maybe after this you will be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Why don't you edit your answer to add your replies to your answer? Seems the solution could be solved after following to the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think middleware for 'layout' is not loaded properly

To load "layout" middleware in your rails application, 
Write below line to your application controller

```
include ::ActionView::Layouts
```